# Not getting expected output (javascript and forms)

Tags: javascript, html

I get the response as **correct** whatever the input is.

```
function vrfy(form){
    if(form.user.value="name"){
        alert("correct");
    }
    else if(form.user.value!="name"){
        alert("incorrect");
    }
}
```

I didn't get any response when I replaced the `else if` with `else` either.

Here is the html part of it but i don't think anything is wrong here:

```
<form method=post>
    <label for=user>Username:</label>
    <input name=user type=text>
    <input type=submit onclick="vrfy(form)" value=login>
</form>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `==`, not `=` for comparison. `=` is for assignment and will always return `true`.

Comment: Thank you.Please excuse me if i have annoyed you all.....Im still new here :p

Comment: That's a very common mistake (even for more experienced coders) - maybe try to adopt spacing to your code formatting to make it easier to spot: `if (form.user.value == "name") {`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Filburt .I'll make sure to use it from now.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning instead of comparing the value (this always returns true), miss double equal sign:

```js
 function vrfy(form) {
  if(form.user.value == "name"){
    alert("correct");
  } else if(form.user.value != "name"){
    alert("incorrect");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was noted in the comments already. No need to try and farm rep fro a typo. Instead vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it with correct operators:

```
function vrfy(form) {
    if(form.user.value === "name") {
        alert("correct");
    } else if(form.user.value !== "name") {
        alert("incorrect");
    }
}
```